# what is the difference between topo to raster and points to raster tools in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, interpolation

I am working with point data, and I've found two ways to create raster data.

1 Topo to raster

[image]

2 points to raster

[image]

the values of each result are different, and here are some pics for reference.
I want to know what are the differences for those two tools and their applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in interpolation (Topo to raster) and conversion (Point to raster). Thats why is your first image "smoother" than the other. Topo to raster interpolate surface from points, even if there is some "gap" in point, function interpolate values from points around. On the other side, Point to raster converts exactly the values of the points to raster, and if there is some "gap", the raster will not be generated here. So this function isn't interpolating. See help for [Topo to raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000006s000000) and [Point to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002z000000).